# GAE and google.appengine.runtime.DeadlineExceededError

Tags: google-app-engine

In my GAE code I upload several files to 3rd party (not mine) server:

```py
for argument in files_arguments:
    files_counter +=1
    file_size = len(self.request.get(argument))/(1024.0*1024.0)
    if file_size <= 1:
        files.append(MultipartParam('file1', self.request.get(argument), 'file'+str(files_counter)+'.jpg', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'))
        # sending file
        data, headers = multipart_encode(files)
        # try 3 times to send the file
        for i in range(3):
            try:
                result = urlfetch.fetch(url=self.request.get('upload_url'), 
                                        payload=''.join(data),
                                        method=urlfetch.POST,
                                        headers=headers,
                                        deadline=10
                                        )              
                break
            except DownloadError:
                logging.error('(POST) ... DownloadError during file upload, attempt ' + str(i))
                pass
            except DeadlineExceededError:
                logging.error('(POST) ... DeadlineExceededError during file upload, attempt ' + str(i))
                pass
        if result.status_code == 200:
```

and on ~10th file I am getting that DeadlineExceededError.
What can I do to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you have not done so already; re-factor your code so that you can defer the execution to a [task](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html). *The deadline for Tasks is 10 minutes vs the 30 seconds for a normal request*.
- Further split down your problem so that each file upload is in it's own task. *This also has the added benefit of making your 'retries' code redundant as tasks can [automatically retry](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue.html#Configuring_Retry_Attempts_for_Failed_Tasks) when they fail.*
- If each upload takes longer than 10mins, then you will have to look at using [Backends](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview.html) to handle the long-running processes.

Comment: Also, look into the async URLFetch API, which will let you do multiple uploads simultaneously.

Comment: @Chris Farmiloe, not sure how to use Task in my case. Currently I do the following - upload the file, save the result data (server returns json with file unique id) to the memcache and once all files are uploaded, I open another url with unique id passed. Based on this unique id I identify records in the memcache and process them. So, I need to wait once all files are uploaded and only after that open another url. How can I do the same with task?

Comment: Probably, I should use deferred task instead (http://code.google.com/intl/ru/appengine/articles/deferred.html)?

Comment: @ Nick Johnson, could you please clarify how should I use that (http://code.google.com/intl/ru/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests.html) taken into consideration that number of files I can have is unlimited and I need to check response for each of them? (i.e. I need to have multiple RPC objects)

Comment: @Nick Johnson, if I upload 5 files per request (urlfetch), then I'll have file size limitation (request should be larger than 1 Mb), right?

Comment: @LA_ The limit is 32MB, not 1MB.

Comment: @Nick Johnson, is it treated as response? http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits

Comment: Chris, if I use urlfetch within the task, will not I have the same 10 secs limitation? _You can set a deadline for a request, the most amount of time the service will wait for a response. By default, the deadline for a fetch is 5 seconds. The maximum deadline is 10 seconds for HTTP requests and 10 minutes for task queue and cron job requests._

Comment: @LA_ you seem to have answered your own question :) ... as I understand it, you can [set the urlfetch deadline](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction.html) **much** higher in a task than within a regular request (up to 600sec)

Comment: @Nick Johnson, is the urlfetch limit for such type of upload 32Mb not 1Mb?

Comment: @Chris Farmiloe, I've changed my code to use tasks (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889981/how-to-use-push-queues-tasks-with-gae) and I am getting TaskTooLargeError now since I pass my uploaded file as payload. What can I do? Should I store the file in datastore and then just pass the key?

Comment: Yes you should just pass keys to tasks, the payload is just a regular request

Comment: I will suggest you to use modules in this case.Split your application into modules.https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/     by using modules the dependency on 10 min task can be overcome.Another option is end previous task and run new deffered task for each upload task.