# How to use push queues (tasks) with GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, task

My GAE application should upload several files to another server (with urlfetch usage).
How to implement this with [tasks](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push.html) with assumption that at the end of last task completion I should perform one more action?

How can I know when the last task is completed?

**Upd**. Is the following approach with Tasks correct?

```py
class Accumulator(db.Model):
    counter = db.IntegerProperty()

def increase_counter(key):
    obj = db.get(key)
    obj.counter += 1
    obj.put()

def zero_counter(key):
    obj = db.get(key)
    obj.counter = 0
    obj.put()

def decrease_counter(key):
    obj = db.get(key)
    obj.counter -= 1
    obj.put()

def get_counter(key):
    obj = db.get(key)
    return obj.counter

class PublishPhotosHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    # where this tasks_counter should be defined? seems not here
    db.run_in_transaction(zero_counter, some_unique_key)
    for argument in files_arguments:
        taskqueue.add(url='/upload', params={'key': key})
        db.run_in_transaction(increase_counter, some_unique_key)

    # here we redirect user to another page '/checkstatus'
    ...
    # nothing is shown to the user here

class UploadWorker(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        key = self.request.get('key')
        result = urlfetch.fetch(...)
        db.run_in_transaction(decrease_counter, some_unique_key)
        # how to return there error, so the task will be retried?
        # nothing is shown to the user here

# this is our '/checkstatus' page
class CheckStatus(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, key):
        if get_counter(some_unique_key) == 0:
            # all tasks finished
            # show the content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an *counter* entity, that stores current count of tasks to execute. And each task. after finish, must decrease value of this counter, in transaction. If it becomes 0, then it's last action, just finished.

Comment: Thanks, splix. I've updated my question with the code. Could you please check it?

Comment: No, it needs to be a persistent entity. updated in _transaction_

Comment: splix, I've updated my code. But looks like it is still incorrect. There is no `SELECT * FROM Accumulator`...

Comment: I also think that I need to delete this counter record once processing is completed.

Comment: `get_counter(some_unique_key) == 0` must be checked at UploadWorker.post. If it equals to zero - it completed, you have to delete it and start there your 'last action'

Comment: splix, if I do so, where should I display the page to the user? at UploadWorker.post as well? will not it be called several times (for each task I request)?

Comment: You should display page just after starting tasks. And, after it finished you can send message to the browser using Channel API, or just refresh page every 10 seconds, using javascript/metarefresh, until tasks will be finished

Comment: Ufff. Looks complicated )). Is there any sample with javascript to do the same?

Comment: Yeah, it looks complicated :) but not so much. I don't know any good sample btw. There is few examples at official gae docs/cookbook, take a look at them

Comment: And, what is the purpose of that counter then? Or, what is the purpose to check if counter value is equal to 0?

Comment: As I understand you need to make an action only when all other are finished? zero value mean that all task a finished, and now you can execute your last action (and send a message to user)

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. But why I need to check if counter is equal to zero at UploadWorker.post, when I'll have to refresh the page (but not sure which page?) with javascript and check the counter there?

Comment: Yes, you can check it on refresh :)

Comment: Have you ever seen an example of such approach?

Comment: No, the example of usage tasks with javascript check if they are finished )).

Comment: I've updated my code. Could you please check that again? (many thanks for your help!)

Answer (score 1):

The code you show won't work - the tasks you're starting aren't in the same local scope as the counter, and may not even be on the same machine. You could use a datastore-based counter as @splix suggests, but this looks like a case where the [Pipeline library](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/) would be ideally suited.

Comment: I would suggest [Fantasm](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/fantasm.html) too