# How to descrease tasks counter if all retries failed?

Tags: google-app-engine

I [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889981/how-to-use-push-queues-tasks-with-gae) counter to keep number of currently running tasks. Once task is successfully completed, I decrease that:

```py
        for argument in files_arguments:
                taskqueue.add(url='/tasks/upload', params={'photo_key': str(photo_file.key()),
                                                           'counter_key': counter_key})
                # count number of active tasks                
                db.run_in_transaction(increase_counter, counter_key)

# task handler
class UploadWorker(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
            try:
                result = urlfetch.fetch(...)              
            except DownloadError:
                logging.error('(TASK) ... DownloadError during file upload')
                pass
            except DeadlineExceededError:
                logging.error('(TASK) ... DeadlineExceededError during file upload')
                pass
            if result.status_code == 200:
                # decrease counter of active tasks
                db.run_in_transaction(decrease_counter, counter_key)
            else:
                self.response.set_status(500)
```

But how can I know that last try is also failed to decrease tasks counter?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to execute code if your task gets cancelled due to too many failures. Instead, you should build your task so that when something goes wrong, it checks its own retry counter, and if it's on the final retry, decrements your task counter before failing.

As I said in your original question, though, you should almost certainly be using something like the Pipeline API - keeping a single global datastore counter for tasks is going to severely limit your throughput.

Comment: with regards to the first part of your answer - this is what I am asking now. How can I know if this is final retry?

Comment: @LA_ By checking the retry count and comparing it to a constant in your code.

Answer (score -1):

If this transaction has failed, it will throw another exception.

As a result response of this tasks handler will have 500 status code, and GAE will try it again, few times.

BTW, note that as handler can be called multiply times, your `urlfetch.fetch()` can be executed few times. Is it working for your?

Comment: splix, let's say I've defined the task to be executed maximum 3 times. It was executed 3 times and 3 times failed. But since there will not be more attempts, I need to decrease the counter. Do I need to catch some other exception and do it there? Which exception then? (It is OK if file would be uploaded several times)

Comment: First of all: you can configure how it will been retried (see `TaskRetryOptions`). And second: you can schedule some cleanup task, that will be executed after several amount of time, and check that everything processed or not (see `Task.eta`)